# Modifying links design for a tumblr theme

Tags: css, themes, hyperlink, tumblr

I'm trying to modify the way links display in the theme I'm currently working on  with the a:link a:hover method in a css file but it don't work and I can't understand why... Any help ? Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what problem are you having? Please be more descriptive.

Comment: I'm trying to get my links black and italic by default, with a line through when "hover".

Comment: Have you tried using !important with your css rules?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (note a:link doesn't exist in CSS):

```
a {
   text-decoration:none;
   color:#000;
   font-style:italic;
}
font
a:hover {
   text-decoration:underline;
   color:#000;
}

a:visited {
   color:#000;
}
```

"a" is the link. text-decoration: none removes the underline, text-decoration: underline adds the underline. font-style:italic adds an italic to the link. the color #000 is black and using that color in a:visited ensures that the link stays black after it's visited (I didn't know if you would want that so I added it anyway).